# Is boost::asio tcp socket shutdown blocking or not?

Tags: boost, asynchronous, tcp, boost-asio, shutdown

boost::asio TCP socket accept/read/write all provide async version, but not shutdown.

In my code, I just call socket.close(), and most of the time it works fine. It triggered a graceful TCP shutdown.

But some times, close() simply close the socket without TCP shutdown. As a result, I have to call shutdown() instead. But I don't want to block my code.
Is shutdown() blocking in boost:asio?
How about close()? Is close() blocking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, the `shutdown()` and `close()` calls in Boost.Asio call the underlying BSD socket implementation.  So there is nothing "special" about Asio's shutdown() or close() calls.

- `shutdown()` doesn't block. It is typically used to disable sends/receives or both (ie, send an EOF to the other end). It will NOT destroy the socket (i.e. the socket resource is NOT freed)
- `close()` will free the socket resource. It may also block depending on the `SO_LINGER` option. But `SO_LINGER` is a tricky beast, to convince you:
  http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2004-June/049093.html and http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?id=2982. 
  However, if you are using non-blocking sockets (i.e. O_NONBLOCK, which is what Boost.Asio is really wrapped up around), then close() doesn't block.

Further reading:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/shutdown 
http://linux.die.net/man/3/close

And if you are Windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738547%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
(read the comments, apparently the documented graceful shutdown techniques don't work all the time..)

Comment: Can you illustrate more on the shutdown() part. My experience always told me shutdown() is blocking, because there might still be date pending, and there are FIN/FIN ACK sequence.<br>

Comment: First of all, a FIN can also be thought of a "don't care" message. While writing such TCP code, its very easy to fall under some variant of the Two-Generals problem (read up on it).

Now, to address your specific question. You would typically only call shutdown() when you are certain there is no more data to send/receive. This has to be ascertained (to whatever degree possible) by the application layer protocol. shutdown() might causes a recv()/write() to fail (which makes sense because that side of the socket is closed)